# Statistical methods to compare two financial series data

Tags: risk, risk-management, statistics, quants

I have two financial series data, `x` and `x'`, where `x'` was formed form `x` using the orthogonal transformation as explained in [Orthogonalized Equity Risk Premia and Systematic Risk Decomposition](https://business.wvu.edu/files/d/d2fd65ec-6fe4-44b5-b3bd-9b84449f3d7e/10-05.pdf).

I was just wondering what statistical methods exist to see if `x` and `x'` are "similar" to each other. As of now, I do not have precise definition of "similar", but I can think of comparing simple summary statistics such as mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis, and correlation coefficient between `x` and `x'`. What statistical methods exist to safely conclude that `x` and `x'` are similar to each other?

**Thank you very much in advance for your help!**

Comment: Whether the two time series are beams of light, sounds or something else, their comparison can done using spectral analysis. If the spectrum of X is similar to that of X', the two time series are similar.

Comment: @stans What if they have wildly different amplitudes like $\sin(x)$ and $20\sin(x)?$